# How do I get the wallpaper to fit the width of my dual monitor setup in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, wallpaper

The wallpaper I'm using doesn't fit the exact dimensions of my monitors combined, so when I set the wallpaper option to `span` I get black bars on the far right and left with the image centered in the middle. What I'd really like to see is have the image be fit to the horizontal width without being distorted, removing the black bars. I can do this on Windows, but on Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity, the only option that doesn't replicate the image on both screens leaves an undesired result.

How can I make it fit the width of both monitors without cropping the image?

Comment: I don't know if answers your question, but please check the following post
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2549/how-do-i-set-up-dual-monitor-wallpaper-ubuntu-nvidia?rq=1

Comment: It does not answer the question, as that answer regards the use of `span`. And my question states that `span` doesn't provide the wanted functionality